# Distinguishing GET and POST request from routes in Laravel

Tags: php, authentication, post, laravel-5, get

I'm using laravel 5.5 and I'm trying to do authentication for multiple user types(level 1,2,3) with different registration forms for different levels. How should I modify the routes given below so that it's able to distinguish between get and post requests?

```
    Route::get('/user_level_1/register','Auth\Level1RegisterController@showLevel1RegistrationForm')->name('userlevel1.register');
    Route::post('/user_level_1/register', 'Auth\Level1RegisterController@register')->name('userlevel1.register.submit');
```

Comment: use middleware for that

Comment: I need separate tables for different user levels. So I'm trying to create a separate authentication system for each.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Route::get('/user_level_1/register', function()
{
  return view('level1view');
});

Route::post('/user_level_1/register', 'Auth\Level1RegisterController@register')
 ->name('userlevel1.register.submit');
```

This worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

```
Route::get('/{steps}/register','Auth\RegisterController@register')->name('userlevel1.register');
Route::post('/{steps}/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@doRegister')->name('userlevel1.register.submit');
```

And inside the controller RegisterController method, Do like below.

```
    function register($step) {//for get request
       if ($step == 1) {
       //do something for step 1
      }
    }

 function doRegister($step) {//for post request
       if ($step == 1) {
       //do something for step 1
      }
    }
```

It might help you.